# Read File and count the words in column in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in python and I need some help on read the file and count the word in column.

I have 2 data file, which is category.csv and data.csv.

category.csv:

```
CATEGORY
Technology
Furniture
Office Supplies
```

and below is data.csv

```
CATEGORY
Technology
Furniture
Technology
Furniture
Office Supplies
```

First, I want to select the 'Technology' in category.csv and match it with data.cvs, after that, it will start to count 'Technology' appears how many times in data.cvs.

```
import csv  # import csv file
filePath1 = "category.csv"
filePath2 = "data.csv"
with open(filePath1) as csvfile1:  # open category file
    with open(filePath2) as csvfile2:  # open data file
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(csvfile1)  # dictread file
        reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)  # dictread file
        for row1 in reader1:  # read all row in data file
            for row2 in reader2:
                for row1['CATEGORY'] in row2['CATEGORY']:
                    total_tech = row2['CATEGORY'].count('Technology')
                    total_furn = row2['CATEGORY'].count('Furniture')
                    total_offi = row2['CATEGORY'].count('Office Supplies')
                    print("=============================================================================")
                    print("Display category average stock level")
                    print("=============================================================================")
                    print( "Technology      :", total_tech)
                    print("Furniture       :", total_furn)
                    print("Office Supplies :", total_offi)
                    print( "=============================================================================")
```

But i'm failed to count it with above code, can somebody help me ? Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: Reformatted to 4 spaces for OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution -

```
import csv  # import csv file

filePath1 = "category.csv"
filePath2 = "data.csv"

categories = {}
with open(filePath1) as csvfile:  # open category file
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  # dictread file
    for row in reader:  # Create a dictionary map of all the categories, and initialise count to 0
        categories[row["CATEGORY"]] = 0

with open(filePath2) as csvfile:  # open data file
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  # dictread file
    for row in reader:
        categories[row["CATEGORY"]] += 1 # For every item in data file, increment the count of the category

print("=============================================================================")
print("Display category average stock level")
print("=============================================================================")
for key, value in categories.items():
    print("{:<20} :{:>4}".format(key, value))
print("=============================================================================")
```

The output is like this -

```
=============================================================================
Display category average stock level
=============================================================================
Technology           :   2
Office Supplies      :   1
Furniture            :   2
=============================================================================
```